# Represent url address into a graph

Tags: graph-algorithm

I want to represent relation between url address into a graph for knowing that my crawler program on crawling process with dfs algorithm is correct or not ?, with url address as vertices. My question is what type of edges that are correct for represent connection between url address, directed or undirected edges ?

Comment: Unclear. What is the problem you want to solve ? Usually a graph representation is useful so a solution can be found using some graph traversal algorithm. You don't give enough information to answer the question. Please edit question.

Answer (score 1):

I think `Directed Edges` should be required, because you move from one link to the other.

If for any reason you want to traverse back through a path that you have traversed, you can use `parent pointers`, i.e they keep track of current parent of a node during current traversal of a path, and change accordingly if you traverse backward and then explore another path.